# How can I animate a linked armature?

Tags: animation, armature, linked-data

I am currently setting up a workflow in Blender where I want to use reference / linking instead of importing assets, so everybody working on the project will always have the latest assets and so on instead of having to constantly re-import.

Just as you would do in Maya.

My problem is that I have for example a character with rig as a fbx file that I save as a Blender file so I can link to the collection file. The problem is that it is not possible to animate the rig of the character. You can't go in to pose mode or import animation or mocap in to the rig.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Surely You can do that. **After linking you have to make proxy of that linked object** because linked object do not move and etc.
**Go to Object->Relations->make proxy..**
You can now do your work on the proxy of that object.

Comment: Thanks. That's also the conclusion I ended up with. I had hoped there was a way that was more production friendly.

Comment: "They are now fully deprecated as of Blender 3.0, replaced by the new Library Overrides." https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_proxies.html